# Conversion of python code on Machine learning to realise on quantum processor

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I need to realise a Python code program on Qiskit. It works on fuzzy logic. How should I realise the same using quantum processors using Qiskit? Is there any support on realising Python code for Fuzzy logic using quantum logic gates. Fuzzy logic uses IF THEN rules. How is this to be done?. Which logic gate would be appropriate for the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

It is always difficult to force classical algorithms to quantum devices. And this is maybe a signal that quantum algorithms should be something different and new. Actually, quantum systems have unique properties like entanglement, that classical systems don't have.

However, look at the following paper for a study on the relation between fuzzy and quantum logic:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225320983_On_the_Relation_between_Fuzzy_and_Quantum_Logic